# Autofill login credentials in flutter inappWebview

Tags: flutter, autofill, flutterwebviewplugin, flutter-inappwebview

I am using flutter_inappwebview plugin for developing an android browser. Now I need to save and autofill login credentials for different websites like facebook, twitter etc.
I come to know about securely storing login data using flutter_secure_storage plugin but I don't have any knowledge about how to implement this.
I want this feature exactly as it has in Google Chrome. Please help if you can...
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`flutter_secure_login` currently does not support Flutter platform web.
Since this is the case I would recommend using `shared_preferences` found [here](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

Its very similar to secure storage and can be utilized in a very similar way

in the following code i am using it to store my user data

```
    // write to shared preferences
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (!_context.isLoggedIn) {
      if (prefs.containsKey('userData')) prefs.remove('userData');
      return;
    }

    final userData = Map<String, String>();
    userData['refreshToken'] = _refreshToken;
    userData['tenantId'] = _tenantId;
    userData['userId'] = _userId;
    await prefs.setString('userData', json.encode(userData));
```

That can then be accessed to refresh tokens.

```
Future init() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final prefData = prefs.getString('userData');
    if (prefData == null) return;
    final Map<String, Object> userData = json.decode(prefData);
    _authWriter.write({
      'refreshToken': userData['refreshToken'],
      'userId': userData['userId'],
      'tenantId': userData['tenantId']
    });
    await refreshAccessToken();
}
```

Comment: Soory actually I want to know how can I get, save and use the credentials for auto filling when the user will come back again in the same site. I am taking about *webview*.

Comment: I want this feature exactly as it has in Google Chrome